# Get Facebook Marketing API Access Token Using Ads PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-marketing-api

I was wondering how does one get access to the FB Marketing API Access Token using the Ads SDK. Currently am I manually doing this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=
<http://yourwebsite.com/>&scope=ads_management,manage_pages,publish_actions
```

Which returns a code like this:

```
?code=<your auth code>
```

Then I input into the next URL provided by FB:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&
redirect_uri=<http://www.yoursite.com>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&code=<CODE>
```

This gives me the access token, but am assuming there is a better way to get the access token using the Ads PHP SDK provided? I hope. If anyone can help. Please share, thanks!

Comment: For the login part, you should use the “normal” PHP SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0#examples

Answer (score 0):

You can extend an access token to be a 'long-lived' server-side token. This extension will give it a lengthy expiration. More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#long-via-code

You can also authenticate via the PHP SDK as you mentioned. Get started here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/DEVELOPER_GUIDE.md#authentication-

Comment: The authentication part in the Guide just says: "To make any request to the Ads API, you will need to have a valid access token and the user has accepted the ads_management permission." It doesn't say how to get it?

Comment: You can always use the Graph Explorer. Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview#testing

Comment: Yea I kno, I have that in my question, I was just wondering if there was an SDK method. Ah well cant find one. Will just use Graph API